# Create IOS 6 Address Book Group

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I have seen questions about adding address book group's on here before; however, most of them contain ABAddressBookCreate() instead of the new ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions() and Xcode throws a warning when using the previous code.

I guess my main question is what is the proper way to: 1. Check if a group exsist and 2. create the group if it doesnt in IOS 6.

Thanks!